# Problems when printing a circular singly linked list

Tags: javascript, linked-list, circular-list

I have a circular singly linked list code:

```
class Node{
    constructor(value){
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class LinkdeList{
    constructor(){
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
    }

    empty(){
        return this.first === null
    }

    insert(value){
        let newest = new Node(value);

        if (this.empty()) {
            this.first = this.last = newest;
            this.last.next = this.first;
        }else{
            newest.next = this.first;
            this.first = newest;
            this.last.next = this.first;
        }
    }

    traverse(){
        let aux = this.first;
        while (aux.next != this.first) {
            console.log(aux.value);
            aux = aux.next;
        }
    }
}

let linked = new LinkdeList();
linked.insert("David");
linked.insert("John");
linked.insert("Adam")
linked.insert("Bob");
linked.traverse();
```

And when I tried to print the list, I just get in console 3 names:

```
Bob
Adam
John
```

And as you can see I push 4 names in my linked list. I tried to print the values of my list in the `traverse` method, but It didn´t work because I don´t get in console:

```
Bob
Adam
John
David
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop stops one step too early. This is a good case for a `do ... while` loop. You should also protect it from failing when the list is empty

```
    traverse() {
        if (this.empty()) return; // <---
        let aux = this.first;
        do {
            console.log(aux.value);
            aux = aux.next;
        } while (aux != this.first);
    }
```

Some other remarks on your code:

- As in a non-empty circular list it is always true that the head follows after the tail, it is actually not needed to maintain a `first` reference. Just keep a `last` reference, knowing that you can always get the head of the list via `last.next`.
- `console.log` should not be used in a class method for anything else than debugging. Give your `traverse` method more flexibility by making it a generator. That way you leave the decision of what to do with the values to the *caller* of that method.
- As in a circular list a node should *never* have a `next` property with a `null` value, don't assign `null` in the `Node` constructor. Instead give it a self-reference.
- Name the `empty` method `isEmpty` as it more clearly indicates that this will not empty the list, but will return whether it is empty.
- Fix a typo in the class name: `LinkedList`

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = this; // self-reference
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.last = null; // No need for a `first`
    }

    isEmpty() {
        return this.last === null;
    }

    insert(value) {
        const newest = new Node(value);
        if (!this.isEmpty()) {
            newest.next = this.last.next;
            this.last.next = newest;
        }
        this.last = newest;
    }

    *traverse() { // Generator
        if (this.isEmpty()) return; // Guard
        let aux = this.last;
        do  {
            aux = aux.next;
            yield aux.value; // Don't print. Yield instead.
        } while (aux != this.last);
    }
}

const linked = new LinkedList();
linked.insert("David");
linked.insert("John");
linked.insert("Adam")
linked.insert("Bob");
// Caller of traverse can decide what to do: we want to print:
for (const name of linked.traverse()) console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine! You just need to tweak your `traversal()` method because the while loop breaks before it gets a chance to log the last node.

You can try something like this:

```
traverse(){
    let aux = this.first;
    while (true) {
        console.log(aux.value);
        aux = aux.next;
        if (aux == this.first) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will expand an attribute (`count`)

```
constructor() {
  ...
  this.count = 0;   
}
```

Calculate it when insert is called

```
insert(value) {
  ...
  this.count = this.count + 1;
}
```

If there is an extension removal method later, remember to calculate it

```
remove() {
  ...
  this.count = this.count - 1;
}
```

And adjust the conditional expression of traverse,

replace `while (aux.next != this.first)` with `for (let i = this.count; i > 0; i--)`

> I prefer trincot's answer, my answer is aimed at a small scope of
> code changes.
>
> In practice I will design it with a similar structure(trincot's answer).

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkdeList {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.first = null;
    this.last = null;
  }

  empty() {
    return this.first === null
  }

  insert(value) {
    let newest = new Node(value);

    if (this.empty()) {
      this.first = this.last = newest;
      this.last.next = this.first;
    } else {
      newest.next = this.first;
      this.first = newest;
      this.last.next = this.first;
    }
    this.count = this.count + 1;
  }

  traverse() {
    let aux = this.first;
    for (let i = this.count; i > 0; i--) {
      console.log(aux.value);
      aux = aux.next;
    }
  }
}

let linked = new LinkdeList();
linked.insert("David");
linked.insert("John");
linked.insert("Adam")
linked.insert("Bob");
linked.traverse();
```